# I am pretty sure I am making a stupid mistake, but this code gives out an output that is just too long to read

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, operator-overloading

I think I am messing up somewhere between the pointers.
I do not know if I am supposed to change Book* to something or not.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

```
istream& operator >> (istream& is, Warehouse& warehouse){

    int counter = 0;
    Book* temp;
    Book* headNode;

    is >> headNode;
    while (!is.eof()){
        temp = headNode;
        is>> headNode;
        headNode.setNext(temp); 
        counter++;
    }
    warehouse.bookCount = counter; 
    warehouse.head = headNode;
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem 1

```
is >> headNode;
```

is wrong. Reading a pointer from a file does not make sense. There are two such lines in your posted code.

#### Problem 2

```
while (!is.eof()){
```

is wrong. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/10147399)

I am not able to suggest a fix without seeing the contents of the file from which you are trying to read the linked list data.